# Base64 Image Rendering

Tags: reactjs, image, react-native, components

Trying to render an image base64 for some reason is not showing what am I doing wrong code

```
<Image resizeMode='contain' source={{ uri: 'image/jpg:base64,' + image }}
 style={{ width: '100%' }} />
```

the image variable is long base64

```
let image = '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAoHCBISFRISEhISEhIVGhQaGhAcDxESEg8UJSEZGSUhHCQpIS4zKR8rLRoaJzgmKy8xNTU1HSQ7QDtAPy40NTEBDAwMEA8QGhISGDYeISE0MTQxNDQ0PzQxND81NDQ0NTQxNDQxNDQ0NTE0NDQxNDQxNDE0MTQ0NDc0MTQ0NDQ0Mf/AABEIAJYAlgMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAcAAABBQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAFAAIDBAYBBwj/xAA5EAACAQIEAwYEBAYCAwEAAAABAhEAAwQSITEFQVEGEyJhcYEykaGxQlLB0RQjM2Lw8QdyQ7LhFf/EABoBAAMBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIDBAEFAAb/xAAqEQEAAgICAgIBAwMFAAAAAAABAAIDESExBEESUXEygdFhkeETIjOhsf/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8AOWeHIJK8vOKbguHTc725cbu0BdxPhAHKruJVQuWNT50G7R4oW0TCpoXi5d11yfhT33rnVo73tjBdSbhlt+I4os0hDDN/ZZB8K+rfqa3PFMQqLlGgA22AA2FUuy/Df4XD5nH825DvpqsjRfYfWaF8YxeYkTR5nqp75YVDbuC8diCxJoY5/wB1YuNNUrxB0O27dY5D3qZdsurUqSD+Ot5sknNylSA3oabduwCT/quY2xBUxroZ6VDctlxptPlqR+lNpUskG9mo7gjiqBmzLcz+WUqF9OtUhac7a+c71oTbPNFI6ZYpr4W2fwFfeqmoHE56bd+5nrzusZpA6TUBuyZFaxOAd8pKHMR+CfFVB+CZSQZB/KRWCHqY1YDAJ503KWIX60VucEua5V+Rmo7fCbqsDlMjlEUXyAmfF3L/AAB3F23ZOtvUsh20EzT7+L7s38TuxYpbXq2w+W9d4Kjo91mBD5GyCN2Om/IU5MGDdtm5ct91aEhM/id9yTy3pSm2OB0TqW2s2Uw664jEeJ23ZVO8/OKu8ZwNqwlqwizd0ZzuVHIRTuEJluXMTeNsvqVthwxMfCo+9LhaXLmI766NcxaDsNJ+QFLBtbX1z+YxSpA10MNIIjfSCD0NKtBxZWxjTh7WqzmYCCw5SedKnaYv5zSGUL3bjA2kBdupA2HudKEdk8A+NxTXrolVIuPzGY/Anppt5U3tTisqW8Mu7w7jmQPhHuda3XZrhoweGVWjvG8bnqxG3sNKyqabPRA16JNxzGZRH+TWMxNyTRLi2KzMf81oLcNTWtva9vP+JXiqf2lbEXVQSxA996qYZe9bQkagtpoy9B9qcMFbZRdvy2cmBmhUUGBVzDFVVypHQCdl5UHBs9x/f4lLiDydOZ26Cg7pcUyJ9QaIX8Vkc+LKY00nQ71044t+IH2FVYRrUddyXPYs631Bgxlwb6+RFPHEOq1be4G3C/Kqz2FO2ntTxq9kn+Njpk2G4jlYFCVbl5mtDxDEF7f8y3F0R49l9zz9KH9meDZn71xNtNtPjflHpWsuWrbTmTTzMzXN8rzKY7fGvL7leDC2N2nn2J4jct6TlfXxR4QegH60OxvaDEho7zPAkBkSWXlOk6/YVqu0HDUYN3S5W6RIYe/OsDxHhV22xMRI2zEkDypnj56ZDvX5h5cFqmw2SXF8fbECGJtwF8K6W3PVjuPqKHE6/wD2aoXrDDcQekbUrF8qYbbr0q4DXEjd75hNXqRbzjZmHoxFRKK6BXoMIYfjmKtaJeuKOgaR9aVDiKVZo+pm2eq9k8GcbjHxDj+WjZyNxpoi+0T7VuuO4vKuUf4aq9kuHDC4VMwh3Gd9NZI0HsIoVxfFZ3Pl96TlQCp75f4jKG7bgzEPQ7G3xbUseU1auNNZ3tVcIQKp1J2/tG9IqfK0s2VruVLPaZcj2L9svbk5WBEpJ0BB3FAXtFfhZ18gxFdvJktW9Yd2LzEwNhUaYozDFY/NEx0kVUUK717kxdTmagqGAzQTA1jyqI4UcpFWsJindEeEBYDZIFSF7n+CtFDRBa/J2wf/AA9wfDJ9qIcG4dcvXFtspVd2eNAo3qxhcPfu5u7lsu8ECK1XZnCC2ha88O5HhJ1C8h5VN5XkNMbrW+j+YdKG9+oZtLbtottAAF2FDeI3gNqdi7a5jlYHWImYPSqmMsETJELzmda+c3Ztt5nRw0DXPcHYtwql25eVYrFBrjlif9Ua4zjlYZVJJnbkKE2zO9dDBVrX5a5ZXYOmUbmER9HHvzFZvieHVWIXlz61q8e+VdNzWcxOHJBPrXU8az2vE5vl1r0HMhwDyCp5c/KrlD8MIb2q7mqzuc5I4ilTc1cr0yfSnGsTkSB/nSsRiblHu0GIlo6VlsRc1qC1vktvtleGmoi1YrjuL7x2jYaD0o/xXHZEaDq2g/WsbfuSfM8vOnYae5ua3BWWbVl7qd4wGRMqZpiSQYA+WtQvgwenqdl86KuyratWkkhQXcwQGunf1gAD51QvMIgmJ+tOOwieSst3OOi2AqsoCgABU5DzJode487fmPq37UIxRCsRzqDvKZoOiLN+2eltxjLhUNu33YdFDhdcxkiSTsTVfiXFsRaSyBby6Jqxlm0EkiqPZfFviEs4YOVyN4kie8tzm0Eakajrsa2HE8GuJK2lt5mB+LLqvvyArl58lKXK2N9rOjip8qrvXBIcDxY90lwgS7CRJJVp1HvFMxfFC2e2QWuLmLIDLIs6Fo00nrT+IXbNkLh7YBW2viaNXby8hyrz5cayXWYXHQkr4laHgb60nxvGx5bNk0DxHZslsVBDlPcLNjNSCjDXf4h9P1q1hwGGYbdI1FULmPe94WW3dP4Xju7y+pEA+9W+zz50uZ5zp/bAA5SeZ+ulV+RgrWq1eovxs9rW1b3OY7AksG3X/wBTVDE2gAf23rQAlleBsOvlWe4i/hnn0pfjtrAPqH5Na12/cAEeJiKeDXFWnRXSJyFjSa7SIpVsyfQ+L4G105i4U9Asg/tVE9jc294j0QT96OtxdOn1qN+OouwJPQak1yTLhE3ZT8SoMvomY4p/x+jhQr3GP5iyBV9orLYbsBde86JeRim7BCUUn8xPPyE16RjONMLL3ChQkEKJ1k6TQnA40WLCiYzZmY/iZjzrz5Ne8ap9Q648lh2G+oJt9hrFoRfv3Lrc8oFtB5Dc1FiuDcNtqWNvNlBgZ3JPvU2N4i1zQSB1nU0Ex18ZWUHxEHTpSgyXflZT+gyvHgqAW5jcZhcI1t0GEtIRziTvpB3msBxbhRtHMvitsfCZkqTyPn0r1HgarfD3H0S2paIgFyI1O0gZvnWd/h1uF7ZHhJOXWGGuhHmKox5v9N1tfvc9bBW9bAAnUn/42QJeRCSzgM5EDKhiIHOddTXoXF7wtIzlMrPAzDeOhHU1512GRsPjLi3NCqOZOzCRr6V6TjbwuDL4XVt/yqP851B523OWOTRE4qo12dd/tPP8XYcsXUBydcmaTHnWZ4pwpwS6KWQ6lI8aHmCOdaTiCBLrC34QPxfiHWD0pWE1GszuSZJqvEuPSdMvuVymnuYyzhc0jxTpGse0VruFYR7KQZVm+PXUjkD7T8/KitvDjfpzjX50sSYEfWszZ23+06g48FaO4HxdoKhy/EdBDEamobnZlrkfzoEAkEhmM/pVxmEyQzAeEKBJZjvFRYniHd2i9xGQq3hB0ZgeS+tZRycFXmFelHbY4mUx+F7p2QOHyx4oj29agiq1zFuzM7GSxLH1JqRMRO499669apU3yzgXT5PxNEly0qJYTg+IvILlq1cuJMZwNJ6UqKDNd/8AoNzJPvtVzAcXVT4tP7tTNGsPg7S7W0B65QfvU/dDovpAqG3jFhEnQPIPUp4vHd8jBUbwwQZzFtfL7UOv4jMRm8MAeE6EaUfGAtFCcigtOoGUkA9R6UMxvCcwzozSOTGQ3lO9Jp4rRQ6/7jKZ6654gXF4oKNAx9FpvBBhrhZsSSImEzBSx6senpU9ywVlLgKsPwkfbr61fxF+2ixaso+3xKCY89KywhrTuUD8zh4kWNxlvL3NrLbwy66GczHUydyaz+JD3CuQZEUzOzuf0q3iXJOfuBPRUCovqetUbhvXNzkU8lMmPWhpj1z/AOxjqoVDiP4XxEo5dvG6FgCVzGDoR5g0U4lxO5fQvbnL+IABTA8tq5wjhSsxQMilVLEFgHZR+Ubk1LjsLbsOptlijqTBMgnY69ecV7dWwJ31x9QN6deyUEU5QzKHG8iVb3FLCNnJ8BSDtM+hmlYcqGVpPiMeSnl96sWrqjoPeK1XkCGpseoQQzI6VUxpyqSa4+OVQYk+cQN6q3rhaXbYfCNp8yKTXGjzC+e+pTxPErdgEHMbkSBplAPU+tBG4jcuf1MrJ+QoCD+v1rQcQwtu/h38A7y2M4ePE2skHyj7Vkjcnauthw1rUU5nH8jyL2sm+PUdewuHfZXtHqGzofY61Xbhz+HIyXAzKoIMEMTABB1qXNXe9YCAdN8vInrT9PqSr9zZ9q+IHAWMLg8O2W4AHcjeIIE+pJPtSrF3b+Y5iMzQBLOx0G0TSr3xPuDPZEepM/Tfp515nhuP4m2xAfOo/C4zfXejuD7Y2oHeo6N1HjT160xBglkmzvPso2UR+5qrmhl/7dZ50NwfGLN7+ncVz+XNDD2OtTvf29RXjGb37hOR1pl24EuPDrmEbc58juKhxfBSq5rbSfyEgH2POpcAYLOY/YdatIGutAPhG58qHJirY5IWHPerw6IIt4W8UymyWCsWBBSASIIiddqGYnC3pOW0y6nXITlPQDatbisTli3b9PNmNT47FGxaCpqRpM7sdzUN8BXqdCnlWdbCYJuz9z42R80/GZDZvLn8ql42rYdcOHch7keAiR5PPKYiteJRUJ8d94Op0toeQHKg3/IlmbVt2XKyXFCeSkEkDy0FA4Xmz6hvk/KxXXf95ncVZxlwJKHIB4SijK07mQd9KrYbBOTJkeok+dX8JxB1QqD4W1ifhPUU+3fJ/wBVM5L1HYa9alNcQvKsj7rKNNfMmTQriWIIUgVoLeGZyFUFmbYcya5d7H4m4fFkRObFwYHoOdDiu2tvXB7hZfhWqb0xvZzDlsOXcaOrAD+06UEfsgrf0bxB18DrpPSR+1btLIt2iiiAogDlA00oJgGJcgagn5da7FLCTiXOeJ5vcDIzI4yspII6EUpot2ywrpibjlTkfKVePC0CCJ60CFyjGLeJNFdpgeuVs9LhO9QuamJ0qs7UbAO5GWIMgweoMEe9a7slxl7j9xeY3JEo51YEciedY5zNaDsrby4myeZJ+UGvHcy3U9K4c4DlWEzED0opfv5V008tpoU9uCGHKrmOtsxCqJ2+tbZ0QMfLGcOEsbjfh2HVz+w+9d4q+ZD/ANlP1g/epQndqqjluerHeosXbzIaTY+Q/wBJSOrD9yXEAJfVzqrhco5TzFZjt7jzdurZBlbQ1E6FzvPoIFHLzvcw5yGLqA5TvDAaVhQhcBySzH4ydTn5k+tT51K/E98yrxQbfJ7OI+yYAmrVt415U7B4C5dYJbQsfkFHUnlWs4ZwC3ahr0O/T/xp7Hf3qUw2sJ6lt/IrRHfP1Iuy2JQBy4M+GGg6DWQDy5VqL1lWtMw8MaydNKrXsVZ7soIJMeERAg700XEdQrnwrymAP3oShjA5e5Jezks26gfE3f5Ux4ZYAx8Q3n70M4JYy57h5kx59T+lEeLYlXRlWANMo9DEfI07hXDncFUElV11gT+9W4ng3J7+4OxtoMChAdDOhEj0rK8R7IpcBfDHu352GPgJ/tJ2+1b67hHU5HQqepEAjrNQtgU3J19aoE9RT1zPE7qFCVYEMCQQRBUjlSr0/tB2TtYplZH7q4N3ie8HmOo612tmTzpzNREV1mrgEkAbmjgnUfhrWYydh9TWn7J2s18t+RGPuYAoOiZVAFafsZa/rv8A9F+5r1TmLs8LNqUmtLgEW7bDR41GUnbUCAflFZ/DiVT5e4orwi7kaDs2h8jyNeubION0/mUcXbyyOk1XtmdKM8YsQ08m+9BshDRU1bIoyuxsGVxbNp2aJRht1ahGC7N3Ll13B7uwdS8wSeYUc/Xat7ZwiMkuJihnFMTHgXwiPhywAKG6W0Qsdmu09wQ9/J/Lsylsc5l38ydzURM76+ZM120M1WBhTRleO4DbmDnukGBU1/EkLkn186mu4KCGjXryobiQQSDQtTe2MrdeJ2wczidhr8ta0fB8Y65sh+LWIkHl+lZ7DplS5cPLQHzNEsI2Sy7n8KJ9RW1qbg2XU7xfib3nImMukDShN5HT4bgn8sv94irOGsGJb4m1jpNR30pgPpi/kb1By3idy3sYilXL1vXalRaZ7ZPNyatYBJlunKlSozuA9S2a2HZARYunq4+gFKlRV7irdTXYZtGHQqfmKv2jqRXKVee2ZXo/eE8Sc9kOd1PzjSgwEuo6mlSqS3/J+0sr+maJ7gCkRsI8p61keI4gljPIRHIR0pUqXX9U31B9swfWi2GcxrSpVQ9RZ3CmBsJcOVgSNTvFR8X7O2yGdGKkDUHxK1KlS39LCOyCcdgsuEBBGsk9SZqTCWA1oIdjbtn3BNKlWV9/gm26PzK9oTnbqxUDoBVe9b38q7Spteop7g24tKlSpk9P/9k=';
```

image is valid you can try to decode on base64

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `Image` component to this

```
<Image
   style={{ width: 200, height: 200, resizeMode: 'contain' }}
   source={{ uri: 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + image }}
/>
```

This will work

[Working Example Here](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/base64-image)

Comment: @thaInsanity Happy to help. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Comment: thanks mate !! great .. everything working as expected !